# sending email from Java Application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code for sending mail but I am getting exception.

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25, response: 421

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class SimpleEmailClient {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
            String to = "rajasekharb974@gmail.com";
            String cc="raj479.mits@gmail.com";
            // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
            String from ="brajasekharreddy@chn.aithent.com";
            String host ="localhost";
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            // Setup mail server
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
                    InternetAddress(to));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new 
                    InternetAddress(cc));
            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Email Notification");
            //  set the actual message
            message.setText("Hi,\n\nAcknowledgement Message :: \n\n"+"\n\nThanks,\n"+"Raj");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}*
```

Comment: SMTP [421](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) means "Service not available, closing transmission channel" so maybe you should check your local smtp server logs

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? You're trying to send a mail using the SMTP server on localhost, listening on the default port: 25. The message tells you that it can't connect to this server. My deduction is that you don't have such an SMTP server running on your machine. Do you?

Comment: Yes I dont have any SMTP server but how to solve the problem I got?

Comment: By installing an SMTP server, or by changing the host value in your code in order to use an SMTP server that actually exists and accepts sending mail on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this:-

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {    
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
         String from = "your_mail@gmail.com";
         String pass ="mail_pass";
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
       String to = "reciver_mail@gmail.com";

       String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

       // Get system properties
       Properties properties = System.getProperties();
       // Setup mail server
       properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
       properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
       properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
       properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
       properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

       // Get the default Session object.
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

       try{
          // Create a default MimeMessage object.
          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

          // Set From: header field of the header.
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

          // Set To: header field of the header.
          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                           new InternetAddress(to));

          // Set Subject: header field
          message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

          // Now set the actual message
          message.setText("This is actual message");

          // Send message
          Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
          transport.connect(host, from, pass);
          transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
          transport.close();
          System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
       }catch (MessagingException mex) {
          mex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting following Exception:javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
 at

Comment: dont know what is happening there. I  have just sent a mail with the code

Comment: you may add the jar from here: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home                  and let me know if can help you

Comment: another thing is your **from** should be gmail account

Comment: Still I am getting the exception can you specify the jar file names to be added

Comment: what is **from** email account? it should be gmail account.